# SQL Server: How to Capitalize Letters in Char Containing Numbers

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, char, uppercase

I was struggling with this problem. I cant seem to get a postal code to always look like this format 1234AB.

```
pc CHAR(6) NOT NULL  
CONSTRAINT CK_pc CHECK( pc LIKE '[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]')
```

This does the job for correct numbers and letters but it wont capitalize the last two letters.

For instance:
If I would type 1234aB, it would be stored in the database exactly like that while I want it to be stored like this 1234AB.

I think I need to use a trigger or procedure here but I'm not sure how.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know but a database filled with random ab, Ab, aB, AB at the end just doesn't look good right?

Comment: @Forklift on the contrary, the default collation is not case sensitive but there are tons of collations that are case sensitive.

Comment: @Sean I am not familiar with the rest of the database's function, so it seemed out of scope of the question to have OP change the collation for this insert.

Comment: I was commenting that you stated that sql server is not case sensitive. That indicates it is incapable of being case sensitive but that is not the case (pun intended). :)

Comment: Why just not add a `UPPER()` in your `INSERT` command ?

Comment: @FabienTheSolution this does the job! But shouldn't this be done by a trigger or procedure?

Comment: It depends how you insert you data in the table but yes, a trigger can do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the code where the INSERT is, use UPPER like this :

`INSERT INTO PostalCode (pc) VALUES (UPPER('1234ab'))`

In case you don't have access to the code where the INSERT command is, you can remove the constraint and use a trigger ([CREATE TRIGGER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)) to ensure that data stored will always be in upper case :

```
CREATE TABLE PostalCode(
    pc CHAR(6) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TRIGGER PostalCode_INSERT_UPDATE
       ON PostalCode
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

       UPDATE PostalCode
        SET pc = UPPER(pc)
        WHERE pc in (SELECT INSERTED.pc FROM INSERTED)

END

INSERT INTO PostalCode
       VALUES('1234ab')

SELECT * FROM PostalCode   

pc
1234AB    

UPDATE PostalCode SET pc = '1234ab' WHERE pc = '1234AB'

SELECT * FROM PostalCode       

pc
1234AB
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can use collation to make this constraint work but it is a little funky. You have to include the collation in the constraint but you also have to check for equality since the default collation will become ignored.

```
create table CapTest
(
    pc char(6) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS not null
)

alter table CapTest
add constraint CK_pc  check(pc LIKE '[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]' AND pc = upper(pc)) 


insert CapTest
select '1234AB' --this will work fine

insert CapTest
select '1234Ab' --this will fail the constraint

select * from CapTest

drop table CapTest
```

--EDIT--

Since now it seems you want to actually change the inserted value you will need to use an instead of trigger rather than a constraint. Here is how you could do this with an instead of trigger.

```
create table CapTest
(
    pc char(6)  not null
)

alter table CapTest
add constraint CK_pc  check(pc LIKE '[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]') 

go

create trigger tr_CapTestInsert on CapTest instead of insert as
begin
    insert CapTest(pc)
    select UPPER(i.pc)
    from inserted i
end

GO

insert CapTest
select '1234AB' union all
select '1234Ab' union all
select '1234aB' union all
select '1234ab' 

select * from CapTest

drop table CapTest
```

Comment: This will only let the user HAVE to use the good format right? It doesn't change aB to AB?

Comment: That is correct. You were using a constraint so I assumed that was what you wanted. A constraint does NOT change any value, it ensures that the value received is valid. If you want to change the value you would either do that in your insert or an instead of insert trigger.

Comment: Yes, I would like to change aB to AB. How would this be done with a trigger

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a case sensitive collation. For example, assuming that collation for column `pc CHAR(6) NOT NULL` is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

```
SELECT  col.COLLATION_NAME
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS col
WHERE   col.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
AND     col.TABLE_NAME = 'TableA'
AND     col.COLUMN_NAME = 'pc'
-- returns SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

the I would use following `CHECK` constraint together with **case sensitive** version of the same collation (in this case `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA(
    pc CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CK_pc CHECK( pc COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS LIKE N'[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]' )
)
GO
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableA
DROP CONSTRAINT CK_pc
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableA
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_pc CHECK( pc COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS LIKE N'[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]' )
GO
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableA
DROP CONSTRAINT CK_pc
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableA
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_pc CHECK( pc COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS LIKE '[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]' )
GO
```

and then

```
INSERT dbo.TableA VALUES ('1234aa')
/*
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 6
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_pc15". The conflict occurred in database "Test", table "dbo.Table15", column 'pc'.
The statement has been terminated.
*/
GO

INSERT dbo.TableA VALUES ('1234AA')
/*
(1 row(s) affected)
*/
```

Note: Ase we can see, we don't have (in this case) to change COLLATION of column.

Answer (score -1):

Typically you would not do this in a trigger. You need to create a constraint (as in previous answer) so that data that gets in always valid. Then you can create a function (or a stored procedure) in your code to return properly formatted postal code. Your case is so simple you can use built in sql function upper() as other people suggested. If you have a more complex formatting you can create your own.

```
create function fFormatPostalCode2 
(
    @Code char(6)
)
returns char(6)
as
begin
    return upper(@Code)  -- any other formating here
end

declare @r char(6)
set @r = dbo.fFormatPostalCode('1232aB')
select @r
```